# Get aggregate value from inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This works fine:

```
SELECT TOP 100 ExecutionTime 
FROM [Brokermate_CONFIG].[dbo].[QueryLog] 
ORDER BY ExecutedOn DESC
```

But trying to get the average gives me an error

```
SELECT AVG(executiontime) 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100 ExecutionTime 
     FROM [Brokermate_CONFIG].[dbo].[QueryLog] 
     ORDER BY ExecutedOn DESC
    )
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What's the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add alias to your subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(sub.executiontime) AS average_execution_time
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 ExecutionTime 
      FROM [Brokermate_CONFIG].[dbo].[QueryLog] 
      ORDER BY ExecutedOn DESC) AS sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You've missed `alias` name for Sub Query

Try Below

```
SELECT AVG(executiontime) 
FROM
 (SELECT TOP 100 ExecutionTime 
  FROM [Brokermate_CONFIG].[dbo].[QueryLog]   
  ORDER BY ExecutedOn DESC
 ) A -- You need to have alias name here
```